Why Can't My Desktop Access Apache Web Server on LAN While Laptops Can?
Thanks to Using Domain name instead of localhost in with https in xampp I am running a website on an Apache web server using XAMPP on a new laptop (Laptop 1), which is the host, running Windows 11 and connected to my router via WiFi. I have configured it correctly and can access the website locally and from another laptop (Laptop 2), which is also connected to the same router via WiFi (so they are on the same network). My current working configuration involved adding the following lines to these files on Laptop 1:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1    macamann

C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf I have added directive
Listen 0.0.0.0:8000

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf


    <VirtualHost *:8000>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysites/mann_clinic"
        ServerName macamann
        <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysites/mann_clinic">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>


On Laptop 2 I have the following line in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX macamann


Where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP of my host computer, Laptop 1. And under Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
I have created a new Rule for port 8000 under Inbound Rules. This configuration works, and Laptop 2 is able to access the website from the host computer using http://macamann:8000/ (Just http not https). However, I wonder why the same setup does not work on my desktop computer, which is connected via LAN to the same router and thus on the same network. Even directly using my specific IP address in the format http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/ didn't work. All laptops/computers are running Windows 11 and they all have the same subnet mask 255.255.255.0

I read that outbound traffic is typically allowed by default on most firewalls and network configurations. And since I never changed anything related to this, I would expect it to work by default. When I do a ping from desktop to Laptop 1 it says it is unreachable. But ping works from Laptop 2 to Laptop 1. Also completely disabling Windows Defender made no difference.
Update:
When I unplug the LAN and connect via Wifi then it works. But why? It's the same router I'm connecting to via LAN and Wifi.

Any chance to completely disable Windows Defender to see if it causes the problem?

Yes I completely disabled (turned off) Windows Defender on both computer and host laptop but still couldn't reach the host.
